# Restrict create table privilege to newly created users in RDS PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, rds, database-permissions, postgres-9.6

I am facing an issue while creating a readonly users in RDS PostgreSQL 9.6. I am executing the following SQL commands:

```
---- ###### CREATE ROLE ################
CREATE ROLE readonlyrole_dev;

-- Grant access to existing tables
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyrole_dev;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonlyrole_dev;

-- set the privileges that will be applied to objects created in the future.
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonlyrole_dev;



CREATE USER readonly_dev WITH PASSWORD 'welcome1';
GRANT readonlyrole_dev TO readonly_dev;
```

When I login with the `readonly_dev` user, it has privilege to create the new tables by default but I don't want to do that. I want to keep `readonly_dev` only a read only user.

Note: To revoke the access from the user I am executing

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

which revokes create objects privilege to all old users as well. I only want to revoke create privilege from newly created user.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, and it is not necessary either.

Just deny the user the `CREATE` permission on all schemas. You should use user groups for that - put all users who should have the privilege to create tables in a group that has the required privilege on the schema and revoke `CREATE` from `PUBLIC`.

If you insist that you must have this, try creating an *event trigger* that throws an exception whenever a certain user tries to create a table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please specify how can I move all existing users from PUBLIC to another group? How will it impact on the existing users privileges if new objects in the database are created?

Comment: You'll have to run a lot of `GRANT` statements. New objects in the database always have default privileges unless you change that with `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: what about the event trigger. Can I develop such a trigger that will be triggered only when a specific user is logged in?

Comment: Thanks. Event trigger is working fine for me.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.abort_any_command()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
 if (select current_user) = 'readonly_dev' then
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'command % is disabled', tg_tag;
 end if;

END;
$function$


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER abort_ddl ON ddl_command_start
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE abort_any_command();